# How to query Oracle VM REST API with curl?

Tags: curl, oraclevm

I've searched in the Oracle VM documentation, but I wasn't able to find any example on how to query the Oracle VM REST API from curl or any similar alternative:
https://hostname:port/ovm/core/wsapi/rest/

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
curl -ksu "<OVMUSER>:<OVMPASS>" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
https://<ADDRESS>:<PORT>/ovm/core/wsapi/<URI MAP> ;
```

For xml return, just change the application type to `application/xml`

SOURCE : https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/oracle-vm/3.4/developer/vmapi-rest.html